# Is it practical to increase engine efficiency by preheating petrol from engine heat waste ? is it applied in any automobile?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

I found some article related to preheating the fuel to increase fuel efficiency, but I rarely see such implementation, I assume that it's less effective compared to others

1. But is it really possible to increase the effectiveness of preheating ?
2. Is preheating using fuel waste applied anywhere ?

[enter link description here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.5024622)
[enter link description here](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5218944A/en)

Comment: I did it on a diesel once, but the fuel injection pump compensates the volume based on fuel temperature.

Comment: Heavy oils are routinly heated to flow and atomize better ; in large diesel and furnaces. I don't think I want to be in a vehicle that preheats gasoline.